# Jquery first time tried ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

this is I first time tried ajax , button clicked but nothing happen, should it be alert when success ? Anyone can help me take a look please. Thanks

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qvhsurt/)

**HTML**

```
<input id='submit_btn' type='submit' class='button button-small' value='GET IT' style='width:100%;'>
```

**JS**

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com",
    success: function () {
        var submitted = 1;
        if (submitted == 1) {
            alert("yes!");
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: what went wrong? be more explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work only for the same domain ajax calls. You are making a call to google from you site, which will not work.

Comment: oh! only in same domain ? Sorry I first time tried ajax , now I know . Thanks u !

Answer (score 0):

Your code violates the Cross domain origin policy, You can only make calls to the same domain. if you want to call other domains than you need to use Jsonp.